# how to show infopath form in an email

Tags: development, administration, custom-list, form

is it possible to have a form in an email? I'm needing to create a form that will be sent to a user based on a workflow variable. This email will have two field in it that will need to be filled out by the user. It would be nice if the user could fill out these fields within the email instead of clicking a link to the form. Any help?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try out the method suggested in this post? - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tudort/archive/2006/02/22/536800.aspx

Before sending it as an email, make sure that the infopath form is published to a SharePoint site which has common access. Otherwise the email recepient will not be able to open up the form.

Answer (score -1):

But, do you really want a form in Email? 
Imagine you've made it, and after your user filled in the form and clicked the "Submit" button, shall you send him another email to say "You form has been submitted and saved!" with an "OK" button in it? 
And, imagine you still have made it, and after your user click the "OK" button on the notification email, what's the next? Send him another email to show a list view with query conditions boxes from where he can launch the next round of operations?

Email is a message notification tool, just like a post man calls you at your door, but you still need to get to the door to retrieve your package by yourself, not by the call.
So, give users a link in Email.

Comment: I don't think it's so weird to want a form in an email?  It's kind of like sending a person a survey to fill out, and having it come in your email is convenient (and you don't have to log in to see it).  When they click "OK" it could send them to a web page to say thank you, or something else. (the -1 wasn't mine, by the way).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, BGM! I just want to do things about SharePoint in SharePoint Way. Hope all the people can understand this, and avoid wasting time to do things where SharePoint is not suitable. I'm OK with your scenario, I just don't want to implement it by SharePoint or InfoPath. Yes, you can do it, but that doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: Maybe “showing a form in email" is possible now by using SharePoint 2013 and Outlook. Check this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Reimagine-SharePoint-Development/Reimagine-SharePoint-Development-A-better-way-to-customize-SharePoint and start from 8:20